# '--no-git-tag-version --allow-same-version' semantic-release

Tags: monorepo, semantic-release

I have semantic-release in monerepo that was working fine. We recently upgraded to version 23.0.2 from version version 20.1.3 and with semantic-release-monorepo version 8.0.2 from 7.0.2 since then our packages were not able to release. throwing the errors below

> ```
> 'Command failed with exit code 1: npm version 2.2.0 --userconfig /tmp/3b47c665b78a38995608feea7e3b8449/.npmrc --no-git-tag-version
> ```
>
> --allow-same-version',

I have few packages in my monorepo and each package has a version "version": "0.0.0-development", .

packages

- widgets
- builder (has peerDependency widgets).

I noticed the message below from the logs

> npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
> npm WARN While resolving: repo/widgets@0.0.0-development
> npm WARN Found: repo/builder@undefined
> npm WARN node_modules/repo/builder
> npm WARN workspace packages/builder from the root project
> npm WARN

We are not updating the version in package.json we simply use "version": "0.0.0-development", and allow semantic-release to handle the update in the released version. I spent hours trying to make this upgrade work to no avail. Any help would be appreciated